# GC overhead limit Exception : Unable to take threads & heap dump

Tags: java, gcc, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

We are facing **GC overhead limit Exception** on our servers and we are unable to take heap and thread dump , as it is giving some exception. How to go about solving this issue ? Can some one please help here .

Answer (score 4):

Normal way of taking heap and thread dump relies JMX and so called VM operations.

GC is itself a VM operation, so until it is finished next VM operation cannot start (and JMX is implement in Java so it is also blocked as a part of Stop-the-World pause).

You can try using -F option far `jstack` and `jmap` commands in JDK pause. Forced mode is using OS debug capabilities to access JVM process memory and does not require "cooperation" from JVM process.

Another useful option is `jmap -J-Dsun.tools.attach.attachTimeout=120000 ...` which would increase timeout for `jmap` to wait for JVM to respond.

`-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` is another option if JVM is actually crashing with OOME.

`-XX:HeapDumpPath=filename` option would allow you to control path to generated heap dump.

Both flags are amendable at runtime with `jinfo`. For example.

```
jinfo -flag +HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError <PID>
jinfo -flag HeapDumpPath=mydump.hprof <PID>
```

Finally, you can take OS specific core dump, then use `jstack` or `jmap` pointing to core dump to convert it to Java format.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey, what location would it be created?

Comment: @zubair-ahmed I have updated answer, see `-XX:HeapDumpPath=filename`

Answer (score 1):

Enable `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` and the dump will be created automatically.